Synchronize Synology NAS boxes to replicate our production VM disks
We currently use a Synology NAS to store our virtual machines (but the processing runs on separate ESXi 8 hosts).  We want to create an offsite recovery environment are thinking about deploying an identical Synology NAS to that environment.
Synology offers a feature which keeps 2 of its NAS boxes in sync.  (I think using rsync).  Is it reasonable / good practice to use synology's sync feature to keep this content (primarily VMDK files) synchronized?
My concerns are:

Since each VM's storage is a single large VMDK file, will sync copy it efficiently?
Since the VM's run 24/7, will sync create a valid "snapshot" sent to the remote NAS? (is it recoverable in case we switch to backup site, or can we have corrupt VMDK's).
Will this sync feature negatively impact the primary site VM's running 24/7?

If there is a better way to achieve synchronization using Synology tools let me know.  I see Synology has "snapshot replication", "active backup", "rsync", and more.  I am having a hard time figuring out which will work best for the above scenario.  (Keeping sync occuring at the storage device/synology level)

I'd seriously recommend looking into hypervisor-centric backup solutions, there are even free ones. We can't do any product recommendations here though.

Since each VM's storage is a single large VMDK file, will sync copy it efficiently?

It'll copy any changes, but may not be the most efficient tool.

will sync create a valid "snapshot" sent to the remote NAS? (is it recoverable in case we switch to backup site, or can we have corrupt VMDK's).

If you're using NFS storage, then VMDKs should be locked, ie. not readable. You need to schedule snapshots and can then sync the snapshotted files - need to find out what is what though first. See top paragraph.
If you're using iSCSI LUNs, those might stay readable during use, but simple replication of the VMFS volume will not be consistent.

Will this sync feature negatively impact the primary site VM's running 24/7?

Not more than the storage and network load from reading and transferring does. Trying to continuously sync won't work as you might expect, so you'd need to schedule backup jobs. Again, see introductory sentence.

The problem with VM specific backup solutions are that they don't run on the storage device.  I'm wondering if someone knows of a Synology specific way to achieve this (using Synology tools/packages)

No, they don't run on a NAS, but they do run in a VM. Or as BaaS.
